# OpenGL: Two Vertex Arrays + Two Index Arrays

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to learn modern openGL by starting with an animation of a simple spring-mass system.

I have in my class a spring and a mass, each use an index array to draw and when I do either separately they both work perfectly. When I draw both together the vertex positions are all wrong. I'm guessing that it has to do with how I am numbering the vertex buffers and index arrays and such but I don't understand the inner working enough to figure it out.

```
#include "Spring.hpp"
#include "ShaderPaths.hpp"
#include "atlas\gl\Shader.hpp"
#include "atlas\core\Macros.hpp"
#include <atlas/utils/Geometry.hpp>
const int NUM_VERTICES_PER_LINE = 3;
const int NUMFLOATSPERVERTICES = 6;
const int VERTEX_BYTE_SIZE = NUMFLOATSPERVERTICES * sizeof(float);
GLint numSpringIndices, numMassIndices;
#define NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(a) sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a);
Spring::Spring() : anchorPosition{ 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f }, mPosition{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f} {
    USING_ATLAS_GL_NS; //Short for atlas GL namespace
    USING_ATLAS_MATH_NS;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &mVertexArrayObject);
    glBindVertexArray(mVertexArrayObject);


    ShapeData Spring = ObjectGenerator::makeSpring(anchorPosition, stretch, d);
    ShapeData Mass = ObjectGenerator::makeMass(calculateConnectionPoint(anchorPosition), massWidth, massHeight);
    ShapeData Triangle = ObjectGenerator::makeTriangle();
    numSpringIndices = Spring.numIndices;
    numMassIndices = Mass.numIndices;
    //======= Spring Buffer ======//
    glGenBuffers(1, &mSpringBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mSpringBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Spring.vertexBufferSize(), Spring.vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, VERTEX_BYTE_SIZE, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, VERTEX_BYTE_SIZE, (char*)(sizeof(float) * 3));
    glGenBuffers(1, &springIndexBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, springIndexBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, Spring.indexBufferSize(), Spring.indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //======= Mass Buffer ======//
    glGenBuffers(1, &mMassBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mMassBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Mass.vertexBufferSize(), Mass.vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, VERTEX_BYTE_SIZE, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, VERTEX_BYTE_SIZE, (char*)(sizeof(float) * 3));
    glGenBuffers(1, &massIndexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, massIndexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, Mass.indexBufferSize(), Mass.indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //======= Shaders ======//
    std::string shaderDir = generated::ShaderPaths::getShaderDirectory();
    std::vector<ShaderInfo> springShaders
    {
        ShaderInfo{ GL_VERTEX_SHADER, shaderDir + "Spring.vs.glsl" },
        ShaderInfo{ GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, shaderDir + "Spring.fs.glsl" }
    };
    mShaders.push_back(ShaderPointer(new Shader));
    mShaders[0]->compileShaders(springShaders);
    mShaders[0]->linkShaders();

    //===== Clean ups to prevent memory leaks =====//
    Spring.cleanup();
    Mass.cleanup();
}

Spring::~Spring()
{
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &mVertexArrayObject);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &mSpringBuffer);
}

void Spring::renderGeometry(atlas::math::Matrix4 projection, atlas::math::Matrix4 view) {
    // To avoid warnings from unused variables, you can use the 
    //UNUSED macro.
    UNUSED(projection);
    UNUSED(view);
    mShaders[0]->enableShaders();
    glBindVertexArray(mVertexArrayObject);
    GLint dominatingColorUniformLocation = mShaders[0]->getUniformVariable("dominatingColor");
    //========== Draw Spring ===============//
    glm::vec3 springColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glUniform3fv(dominatingColorUniformLocation, 1, &springColor[0]); //Send the location of the first float
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, springIndexBufferID);
    glDrawElements(GL_LINES, numSpringIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    //======================================//

    //========= Draw Mass =================//
    glm::vec3 massColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glUniform3fv(dominatingColorUniformLocation, 1, &massColor[0]); //Send the location of the first float
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, massIndexBuffer);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numMassIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    //======================================//
    mShaders[0]->disableShaders();
}
void Spring::updateGeometry(atlas::utils::Time const& t) {
    mModel = glm::translate(Matrix4(1.0f), mPosition);
}

glm::vec3 Spring::calculateConnectionPoint(glm::vec3 anchorPosition) {
    glm::vec3 temp = glm::vec3(anchorPosition.x, anchorPosition.y - (18 * d), 0.0f);
    return temp;
}
```

The ObjectGenerator class looks like this for any curious

```
#include "ObjectGenerator.h"
#define NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(a) sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a);

ShapeData ObjectGenerator::makeSpring(glm::vec3 anchorPosition, GLfloat stretch, GLfloat d) {
    ShapeData ret;
    static const Vertex vertices[] = {
        glm::vec3( anchorPosition.x, anchorPosition.y, 0.0f ), // 0
        glm::vec3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ), // Spring Color
        glm::vec3( anchorPosition.x, anchorPosition.y - d,0.0f ), // 1
        glm::vec3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ), // Spring Color
        glm::vec3( anchorPosition.x + stretch, anchorPosition.y - (2 * d), 0.0f ), // 2
        glm::vec3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ), // Spring Color
        glm::vec3( anchorPosition.x - stretch, anchorPosition.y - (4 * d), 0.0f ), // 3
        glm::vec3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ), // Spring Color
        glm::vec3( anchorPosition.x + stretch, anchorPosition.y - (6 * d), 0.0f ), // 4
        glm::vec3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ), // Spring Color
        glm::vec3( anchorPosition.x - stretch, anchorPosition.y - (8 * d), 0.0f ), // 5
        glm::vec3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ), // Spring Color
        glm::vec3( anchorPosition.x + stretch, anchorPosition.y - (10 * d), 0.0f ), // 6
        glm::vec3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ), // Spring Color
        glm::vec3( anchorPosition.x - stretch, anchorPosition.y - (12 * d), 0.0f ), // 7
        glm::vec3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ), // Spring Color
        glm::vec3( anchorPosition.x + stretch, anchorPosition.y - (14 * d), 0.0f ), // 8
        glm::vec3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ), // Spring Color
        glm::vec3( anchorPosition.x - stretch, anchorPosition.y - (16 * d), 0.0f ), // 9
        glm::vec3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ), // Spring Color
        glm::vec3( anchorPosition.x, anchorPosition.y - (17 * d), 0.0f ), // 10
        glm::vec3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ), // Spring Color
        glm::vec3( anchorPosition.x, anchorPosition.y - (18 * d), 0.0f ), // 11
        glm::vec3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ), // Spring Color
    };
    ret.numVertices = NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(vertices);
    ret.vertices = new Vertex[ret.numVertices];
    memcpy(ret.vertices, vertices, sizeof(vertices)); //memcpy(dest, source, size);

    GLushort indices[] = { 0,1 ,1,2, 2,3, 3,4, 4,5, 5,6, 6,7, 7,8, 8,9, 9,10, 10,11 };
    ret.numIndices = NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(indices);
    ret.indices = new GLushort[ret.numIndices];
    memcpy(ret.indices, indices, sizeof(indices));

    return ret;
}

ShapeData ObjectGenerator::makeMass(glm::vec3 connectionPoint, GLfloat width, GLfloat height) {
    ShapeData ret;
    static const Vertex vertices[] = {
        //=================Mass==============//
        glm::vec3( connectionPoint.x - width, connectionPoint.y, 0.0f ), //top Left 0
        glm::vec3( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ), // Mass Color
        glm::vec3(connectionPoint.x + width, connectionPoint.y, 0.0f), //top Right 1
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), // Mass Color
        glm::vec3(connectionPoint.x + width, connectionPoint.y - height, 0.0f), // bottom right 2
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), // Mass Color
        glm::vec3( connectionPoint.x - width, connectionPoint.y - height, 0.0f ), // bottom left 3
        glm::vec3( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ), // Mass Color

    };
    ret.numVertices = NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(vertices);
    ret.vertices = new Vertex[ret.numVertices];
    memcpy(ret.vertices, vertices, sizeof(vertices)); //memcpy(dest, source, size);

    GLushort indices[] = {0,1,3, 1,2,3  };
    ret.numIndices = NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(indices);
    ret.indices = new GLushort[ret.numIndices];
    memcpy(ret.indices, indices, sizeof(indices));

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Are you using the core OpenGL profile?

Comment: What do you mean, when you draw both together?

Comment: If you look in my renderGeometry I am trying to draw both the spring and the mass (the mass is just a rectangle). Right now the sections highlighted by the comments stating "Draw Spring" and "Draw Mass" are uncommented, as well as their corresponding buffer intializers in the constructor. This means that both objects are being drawn. If I comment out the "Draw Spring" section in the renderGeometry method and the "Spring Buffer" section in the constructor then only the mass is being drawn which works as expected. Same for when I do the opposite, the Spring renders as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of fairly fundamental issues in your code, which seem to be based on a misunderstanding of how OpenGL state management works, and how the different types of objects are connected.

The clearest way to illustrate one basic problem in your code is this sequence in your code (with parts omitted):

```
//======= Spring Buffer ======//
...
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mSpringBuffer);
...
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, VERTEX_BYTE_SIZE, 0);

//======= Mass Buffer ======//
...
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mMassBuffer);
...
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, VERTEX_BYTE_SIZE, 0);
```

If you look at the two `glVertexAttribPointer()` calls, they both set up the same vertex attribute (`0`). Since they both set the same state, the second one "wins", overriding the state you set up with the first call. The arguments to the call are the same, but `glVertexAttribPointer()` also implicitly picks up the currently bound `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, which the data will be sourced from. As a result, attribute 0 will use data from `mMassBuffer`, and *never* from `mSpringBuffer`.

The best way to fix this is to use two vertex array objects (VAOs). The VAO tracks the state set with `glVertexAttribPointer()`. So if you use two different VAOs, one of them can track the state used for the spring, and one the state used for the mass. After removing the current VAO creation/bind code, do this:

```
//======= Spring Buffer ======//
glGenVertexArrays(1, &mSpringVao);
glBindVertexArray(mSpringVao);
...

//======= Spring Buffer ======//
glGenVertexArrays(1, &mMassVao);
glBindVertexArray(mMassVao);
...
```

Then, in the draw code, you don't have to bind any buffers anymore, since all the state setup for the attributes is tracked in the corresponding VAO. Instead, bind the corresponding VAO before each draw call:

```
glBindVertexArray(mSpringVao);
glDrawElements(GL_LINES, numSpringIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

glBindVertexArray(mMassVao);
glDrawElements(GL_LINES, numMassIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Of course you'll still need to set the uniforms, etc.

There's another small but important problem in the setup code here:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, VERTEX_BYTE_SIZE, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, VERTEX_BYTE_SIZE, (char*)(sizeof(float) * 3));
```

The values for the two `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` calls are wrong here. They need to match the location of the vertex attributes used in all other calls:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, VERTEX_BYTE_SIZE, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, VERTEX_BYTE_SIZE, (char*)(sizeof(float) * 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

The code does not seem to be binding the ARRAY_BUFFER, before setting the corresponding ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER for drawing. Ex, the below is missing

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mMassBuffer);
```